# Сможет ли Python программа работать на ассемблере?

Tags: python, ассемблер, ос

Вопрос может вам показаться **глупым**, но если я напишу простенькую ОС на ассембелере, смогу ли я на ней запустить python код в в exe файле?

Comment: Если коротко то, нет. В теории можно, но это невероятно много времени займет. Я слышал для микроконтроллеров питон приспособили(Micro Python), как вариант если несколько лет будете копаться в исходниках этой модификации может и получится написать со временем

Comment: Если ваша ОС будет поддерживать все нужные питону (и используемым им библиотекам) вызовы posix, то должно заработать. Только в этом случае ОС станет уже не простенькая, а чем-то вроде линукса. И тогда уж разумней писать ее в основном на Си